# openstack octavia disk-image-creator error

Tags: openstack

I ran diskimage-create.sh from the Octavia 1.0.1 distribution. I supplied no parameters (just accepted defaults). It ran for a long time and finally died with the following exception:

```
ERROR diskimage_builder.block_device.blockdevice [-] Create failed; rollback initiated
2018-10-18 02:28:20.700 | Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-10-18 02:28:20.700 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- packages/diskimage_builder/block_device/blockdevice.py", line 406, in cmd_create
2018-10-18 02:28:20.700 |     node.create()
```

Any clues about where this could be coming from? I am running on ubuntu16.0.4

Thanks for any help. Ranga

Comment: We would need more logs, but maybe this (fixed in newer versions of diskimage-builder) https://bugs.launchpad.net/diskimage-builder/+bug/1698337

Comment: I git cloned the latest and built it from there. That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me (thanks @eandersson ):

```
git clone the master branch of Octavia 
pip install disk-image-creator
bash diskimage-creator.sh
```

I worked this on a Ubuntu-16.0.4 system. I have not tried any options for the diskimage-creator.sh script but it is encouraging to know that it works (without options).